# Web Console/Terminal for OpenVZ Containers

Tags: linux, terminal, console, centos6, openvz

I'm creating a module for CWP (CentOS Web Panel) to support OpenVZ containers. I'm done with the admin panel where you can create/start/stop/suspend/unsuspend/delete and view variable stuff about the containers. On the client side I'm done with start/stop/restart(reboot)/reinstall/change root password/change hostname and status of the container. Now I'm stuck. I want to add web console (php/java/jscript/javascript/python/ror/...) to the client side where I can edit `hostname`, `port`, `username` and `password` used for the connection to put instead of `hostname` to be `$ipaddr`, instead of `port` to be `$vport`, instead of `username` to be `$username` and instead of `password` to be `$password`, variables taken from MySQL DB. I've tried web-console.org and some more, but no luck until now. I have no experience with Java/JavaScript/JScript/Python/Ruby on Rails, just PHP, MySQL, BASH/CSH, so please offer me something that can do my job if you know. Thank you.